# Find the first max value from array from top in scala

Tags: scala

I have an array and I want to find the first max value received while iterating the array.

```
0,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,5
```

So, in this case as soon as the 3 is less than 0 the loop should break and the output should be 3.

Output should be:

```
3
```

Comment: What do you mean by the first max value from the top?

Comment: What does _"top"_ means? what have you tried? what problems do you have? do you have any restrictions? Does it only has to work for ints or for any number or for anything that can define some kind of order?

Comment: You might be inspired by https://github.com/yycfp/unconf/tree/master/2018-02-15-longest-contiguous-increasing-range/scala

Comment: While iterating the array if the third value is greater than fourth the loop should break and the output should be third position value. I dont want to iterate on the complete array.

Comment: @Etisha please edit the question instead of adding a comment. Also, does it have to be an array or can it be a list? finally, what have you tried?

Comment: It can be a list and I have updated the question

Answer (score 2):

You haven't stated how to handle an empty collection. `Option` is a good solution.

```
def firstPeak(ints :Iterable[Int]) :Option[Int] =
  ints.sliding(2)
      .find(pair => pair.head > pair.last)
      .fold(ints.lastOption)(_.headOption)

firstPeak(Array.empty)                     //res0: Option[Int] = None
firstPeak(Vector(9))                       //res1: Option[Int] = Some(9)
firstPeak(Array(0,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,5))        //res2: Option[Int] = Some(3)
firstPeak(List(0,2,3,10,11,12,13,14,15))   //res3: Option[Int] = Some(15)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive approach using **List**

```
def findTopMax(list: List[Int]): Option[Int] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaning: List[Int], currentMax: Int): Int =
    remaning match {
      case x :: _ if (x > currentMax) =>
        currentMax

      case xs :: xs =>
        loop(remaning = xs, currentMax = x)

      case Nil =>
        currentMax
    }

  list match {
    case x :: xs => Some(loop(remaning = xs, currentMax = x))
    case Nil => None
  }
}
```

And here is a *"looping"* (it is technically also a recursion) using **ArraySeq** *(which is an immutable array, you can use a normal array if you prefer or if you are in `2.12`)*

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq

def findTopMax(array: ArraySeq[Int]): Option[Int] = {
  val length = array.length - 1

  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(idx: Int, currentMax: Int): Int =
    if (idx == length) currentMax
    else if (array(idx) > currentMax) currentMax
    else loop(idx = idx + 1, currentMax = array(idx))

  if (length == -1) None
  else loop(idx = 1, currentMax = array(0))
}
```

The trick is that you can always break a recursion when you want.